# PHP + JQuery setting background images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I've got a php variable, which i pass to a jquery script, which I want to set the background of a certain div. nothing seems to work though.

here's the code:

```
<?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); ?>
<?php $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#event-sub-hero").css('background', 'url("<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url ?>")');
    });
</script>

<!-- SUBPAGE HEADER -->
  <div id="event-sub-hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sub-hero-text col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      </div> <!-- end sub-hero-text -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </div> <!-- end sub-hero -->

<!-- END SUBPAGE HEADER -->
```

This is the code it spits out:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#event-sub-hero").css('background', 'url("http://localhost:8888/babble/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/madmen-night.jpg")');
    });
```

Comment: Does the $post_thumbnail_url variable contain the full pathname to the image file i.e. images/pic1.gif

Comment: What is the generated code vs expected generated code?

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: The images is not showing up. The variable does contain the full pathname too.

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-image` instead of CSS `background`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the background of that element with straight up CSS? Maybe the element isn't appearing how you would expect.  Also, I'd use background-image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the double quotes, you shouldn't need them, and as someone else mentioned, using 'background-image' is more correct when you are only setting the background image.

Comment: Removed the double quotes. still nothing .